# How I can check the same conditon when Button is clicked in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
const submitHandler =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    
}
function AdminPannel() {
    let defaultName = "rajeevkhadka";
    let defaultpassword = "nepalkoxro";
    const [username,setUsername] = useState();
    const [password,setPassword] = useState();
    return (
    <>  
        
        {username === defaultName && password === defaultpassword? <div>
        Hey! I m the admin pannel <b>Rajeev Khadka</b>
        all the user are : 
        <ul>
            <li>Samrat Thapa (I need a website)</li>
            <li>Bikash Malla (I need to edit muy photo)</li>
        </ul>
    </div> :  <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <input type="text" value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="submit" onClick={handlePassword} value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>}  
    </>
    )
}

export default AdminPannel;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here, I am checking that if the state called username  and password is filled with defaultName and defaultpassword respectively. if the condition satisfy i want to render admin details which contains ul and others else i want render the input form..
I did that it works but i need to check the same thing in click of submit button.
i m facing the problem that when the state is feild with the correct details it automatically render the ul part...

Comment: Have a new state for tracking the form submission. Show the form until it isn't submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
function AdminPannel() { 
  const [isAdmin , setAdmin] = useState(false);
  const submitHandler =(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault()
      setAdmin(username === defaultName && password === defaultpassword)
      
  }
    let defaultName = "rajeevkhadka";
    let defaultpassword = "nepalkoxro";
    const [username,setUsername] = useState();
    const [password,setPassword] = useState();
    return (
    <>  
         {isAdmin? <div>
        Hey! I m the admin pannel <b>Rajeev Khadka</b>
        all the user are : 
        <ul>
            <li>Samrat Thapa (I need a website)</li>
            <li>Bikash Malla (I need to edit muy photo)</li>
        </ul>
    </div> :  <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <input type="text" value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>}  
    </>
    );
}

export default AdminPannel;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
const submitHandler =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    
}

function AdminPannel() {
    let defaultName = "rajeevkhadka";
    let defaultpassword = "nepalkoxro";
    const [username,setUsername] = useState();
    const [password,setPassword] = useState();
    const [adminUL,setAdminUL] = useState(true);

    const handlePassword = () => {
    
        username === defaultName && password === defaultpassword ? 
        setAdminUL (false) : setAdminUL(true);
    }

    return (
    <>  
        
        {!adminUL ? <div>
        Hey! I m the admin pannel <b>Rajeev Khadka</b>
        all the user are : 
        <ul>
            <li>Samrat Thapa (I need a website)</li>
            <li>Bikash Malla (I need to edit muy photo)</li>
        </ul>
    </div> :  <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <input type="text" value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="submit" onClick={handlePassword} value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>}  
    </>
    )
}

export default AdminPannel;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [showAdminDetails, setShowAdminDetails] = useState(false);

  const handlePassword = () => {
      setShowAdminDetails(username === defaultName && password === defaultpassword);
    }
```

As shown above, create a local `state` for tracking the visibility of `adminDetails`. Based on that render the template.

```
**`Complete Code:-`**
function AdminPannel() {
    let defaultName = "rajeevkhadka";
    let defaultpassword = "nepalkoxro";
    const [username,setUsername] = useState();
    const [password,setPassword] = useState();
    const [showAdminDetails, setShowAdminDetails] = useState(false);

  const handlePassword = () => {
      setShowAdminDetails(username === defaultName && password === defaultpassword);
    }

    return (
    <>  
        {showAdminDetails? <div>
        Hey! I m the admin pannel <b>Rajeev Khadka</b>
        all the user are : 
        <ul>
            <li>Samrat Thapa (I need a website)</li>
            <li>Bikash Malla (I need to edit muy photo)</li>
        </ul>
    </div> :  <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <input type="text" value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <input type="submit" onClick={handlePassword} value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>}  
    </>
    )
}

export default AdminPannel;
```